# Tire - search elasticsearch multiple indexes and filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

Is it possible to use tire gem to search multiple indices and also have different filter for each one.
I want to do something like this:

```
@_results ||= (Tire.search(["index1", "index2", "index3"],{load: false}) do 
    query { string query, default_operator: "AND" }
    filter :term, index1_field: [value]
    filter :term, index2_field: [value]
    filter :term, index3_field: [value]
end)
```

for the results I want data from index1 containing the query with first filter + data from index2 containing the query with second filter etc

Thanks